# Loop Through Pivot Slicer and Print

Tags: excel, vba, powerpivot, slicers

I am a bit of a VBA newbie and have tried a few different solutions on this site, but am having no luck. I have a dashboard in an Excel file, linked to multiple tables - I want to change the location slicer and print the dashboard for each site.
In a separate file I have some VBA code to loop through the location slicer in a selected active workbook
I think I worked out that because I am using PowerPivot to pull the data in I need to use the slicercachelevel.

The error I am getting now is Run time error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error.

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub DashboardCreate()
Dim wb As String
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim fname As String
Dim location As String
Dim sI As SlicerItem, sI2 As SlicerItem, sC As SlicerCache
Dim index As Integer

location = "T:\Sarah\Weekly Sales Reports\"

Set sC = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_LocationName7")
'loop through

With sC
For Each sI In sC.SlicerCacheLevels(1).SlicerItems
  sC.ClearManualFilter
    For Each sI2 In sC.SlicerCacheLevels(1).SlicerItems
*error appears on this next line*
     If sI.Name = sI2.Name Then sI2.Selected = True Else: sI2.Selected = False 
    Next
 Debug.Print sI.Name
 fname = sh.Range("B11").Value
 sh.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=location & fname    & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
Next

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Try something like `sI2.Selected = (sI.Name = sI2.Name)`

Comment: Hey Tim, thanks for your help, but no luck. It looks like sI2 is causing the issue for me though. When I hover over sI.Name it is showing me the formula with reference to the first slicer item value. When I hover over sI2 is says sI2 = Nothing and then when I hover over sI2.Selected  is says sI2.Selected = <Object variable or With block variable not set>

Answer (score 0):

The loop in this code works in power pivot, I've edited some of the code to fit your question. You can tweak file-name, print settings etc with your code.

```
'This VBA will loop through your Power Pivot slicer and print the results to PDF.
'To get it working change slicer name and storage location in below VBA.

Private Sub PowerPivotLoopSlicerPrintPDF()
Dim SC As SlicerCache
Dim SL As SlicerCacheLevel
Dim SI As SlicerItem

Set SC = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_LocationName7") 'Add slicer name between " "
Set SL = SC.SlicerCacheLevels(1)

'c(ounter) is set to 1, ready to begin
c = 1


'Repeat the a loop until number of prints exceeds number of items in slicer
Do While c <= SC.SlicerCacheLevels.Item.Count + 1

'This makes sure that SI is the correct slicer. Needed for corrent file name.
    For Each SI In SL.SlicerItems
        If SI.Selected = True Then
        SlicerverdiIndex = c
    Exit For
        End If
    Next SI


    'PRINT CODE
    Dim FName           As String
    Dim FPath           As String

    'Define file path for printed file storage
    FPath = "T:\Sarah\Weekly Sales Reports\"   'Choose your filepath
    FName = SI.SourceName

    'Define WHAT to print and how to build file name
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    FPath & "\" & FName & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
    False

    'PRINT CODE FINISHED

'Sets the slicer to the last item in the list
If SlicerverdiIndex = 1 Then
    SlicerverdiIndex = SC.SlicerCacheLevels.Item.Count + 1
End If
SC.VisibleSlicerItemsList = SL.SlicerItems(SlicerverdiIndex - 1).Name

'Adds 1 to the counter, will loop until end of slicer has been reached.
c = c + 1

Loop

End Sub
```